# Try-Catch and how throw work in catch block

Tags: try-catch

I have question about throw. How will the throw work in the following code?
Does the catch block return false?

```
try
{
    //code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You may want to list what language you are using.

Comment: The best thing to do is write some code and run it in the debugger.

Comment: @bodnarbm: yes, but the syntax is probably C++ or somewhat like Java, and the behaviour with respect to the question does not vary between those two languages.  I'd not be surprised to find that C# looks and works very similarly - but I don't know that.

Comment: it is C# code. i forgot to tag it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it rethrows.  Somewhere up the call stack needs to catch it.

The `return false` is never reached.

Comment: No. There will not be a return value

Comment: No, it doesn't return, it exits the function via an exception -- the control goes inside of a catch block up the call stack.

Comment: is there any way to return false and also throw?

Comment: No - if you leave via an exception, you cannot return ordinarily.  The return statement is never reached - it is dead code.

Comment: I guess the question is what would it mean for you to return false and also throw an exception -- if you want the caller to know that something happened, just return false and then the caller can throw if it has to.  Or the caller could catch the exception. Or maybe you need a more complex return that has more information in it.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing and returning false does not make sense. Exceptions are used to indicate when errors occur so there is no reason to also have a boolean flag indicating so at the same time. Let's assume your try/catch is in a BankAccount class. If your client code looks something like this:

```
boolean success = bankAccount.withdraw(20.00);
if(success == false) System.out.println("An error! Hmmm... Perhaps there were insufficient funds?");
else placeInWallet(20.00);
```

You could be doing this instead:

```
try {
   bankAccount.withdraw(20.00);
   placeInWallet(20.00);
}
catch(InsufficientFunds e) {
   System.out.println("An error! There were insufficient funds!");
}
```

Which is cleaner because there is a clear separation of normal logic from error handling logic.

Answer (score 2):

There is no return value. `throw` stops the execution of the method, and the calling block will receive the rethrown exception.